# Comparing numbers from a JSON result with jquery

Tags: jquery, web-applications, cordova, parseint

I'm trying to compare the value of some data from an ajax request (json) against a predefined number, and then output some HTML as a result.

Basically, if x is > than y, show 'this'.

I'm saving the bits I need from the ajax request as:

```
var x = [];
var y = [];
var z = [];
```

I believe these are arrays (not sure if this has an impact when I get to my problem in a moment?)

Then I'd like to compare x, y and z against some preset numbers and output something as a result. Here's what I've got so far…

```
if(x > '3') {
    //do some stuff
}
else if(x > '2') {
    //doing something else
}
else if(y > '5') {
    //do this other thing
}
else if(z == '20') {
    //do that
}
else {
    //do the rest
}
```

This isn't working because some of the values are double digit numbers, so I *think* I have to use parseInt, which I've tried, like this…

```
if(parseInt(x, 10) > '3') {
    //do some stuff
}
else if(parseInt(x, 10) > '2') {
    //doing something else
}
else if(parseInt(y, 10) > '5') {
    //do this other thing
}
else if(parseInt(z, 10) == '20') {
    //do that
}
else {
    //do the rest
}
```

However, this isn't working but it's not giving me any errors either. I'm pretty sure a switch statement would be better too but I have a feeling it's not that which is causing the problem.

I'm a designer struggling to get to grips with jquery so please excuse my naivety, any help greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you obtaining the json? if you put something in the last else does it executes?

Comment: Here you can see how comparisons work: http://jsfiddle.net/h6CC2/

Comment: @EH_watch The json is called with this… $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type:'GET',
        url:"http://urlgoeshere.com",
        data:"q=" + coords.latitude + "," + coords.longitude + "&format=json&num_of_days=2&key=apikeygoeshere",
        dataType:'jsonp',
        success:function(feed) { …this all works fine as I can see the result in the console. It's just when I try to manipulate the data that it goes a bit potty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you initially said, the problem is that you are comparing an array with a number, compare a array's index which is numeric to a number..

Comment: If I replace the '[]' with '()' (presumably to save the variable as a string, not an array) it seems to break?

Comment: Good question! There isn't a reason. I'm just working through trying to get the variables saved properly now, hopefully that will put me on a better track. Thanks for your answer though.